# Exception in the moment of vector assignment C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, vector

I've got the C++ library for using in C# code. When it was built for Win32 it seemed to be ok, but then I built it for x64 some weird things started happening. May be it is not connected with platform, but I have no other idea, why it's happening.

So here is the sample below, which is simplified copy of my code and works perfectly in console application for x64, but doesn't in my library. The characteristics of my library: it uses cryptopp library linked statically, I built it myself for x64 and using runtime library = MDd (though it was recommended to use MTd and I tried it also with no effect). Also my cpp library exports methods. I can't remember I changed any project properties except of runtime library and path for linking cryptopp.

This code is called from test project in the same solution and also from C# code with the same effect. Also in the beginning of test project before the test method is run there are a lot of exceptions in KernelBase.dll

```
// library

class SymmetricAlgorithm
{
public:
    SymmetricAlgorithm() {}
    vector<byte> Key;
    vector<byte> IV;
};

class Data 
{
public:
    Data(vector<byte> b) {_b = b;}
    vector<byte> GetBytes() {return _b;}

private:
    vector<byte> _b;
};


// test project

vector<byte> b(10, 1);
Data key = Data(b);
SymmetricAlgorithm sa;
sa.Key = key.GetBytes();
```

The exception message I've got in vector._Tidy() (which is called in the moment of assignment vector to vector in last row) method says:

> First-chance exception at 0x000007fefdaa940d (KernelBase.dll) in >vstest.executionengine.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: >Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework::CSEException at memory location 0x1d26baf0.
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Comment: I edited your post for better reading.  Please check if I made a mistake in my assumptions on which code belongs to the library

Comment: This is the kind of mishap you get when you expose C++ classes across DLL boundaries.  Using /MD is essential.  Mixing release and debug builds or different compiler versions can be fatal as well.  Very unclear how you expect C# to use this code, it can't.

Comment: I hoped to see your answer :) I saw some of your comments on similar topics and according to one of them tried /MD. It didn't help, but may be because trying to find the solution I've changed also something else. Presently I took my library version dated two days ago and tried /MD and it seems to be ok now. So the answer is /MD (or exception wrapping which also was added since that version). By the way, could you please also suggest standard way to pass to C# C++ exceptions in a readable form. P.S. I have wrap classes for mentioned there marked dllexport, so can be used from C#

Comment: Hans, could you please add the answer instead of a comment about /MD to allow me check it like the right one? Thanks.